# moderncv \glqq not working

Tags: moderncv

Why can `\glqq` not be used with `moderncv`?

For example you can use this:

https://github.com/mliu7/latex-moderncv

the problem is: using `\glqq`inside the `\cventry` leads to compilation error

`! Undefined control sequence.`

Anyone knows how to solve this?

As demanded, here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{name}
\familyname{name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2000--2010}{Some degree}
{
%\glqq
University of Narnia
%\grqq
}
{Some city, Some country}{}{}

\end{document}
```

uncomment `\glqq` to get minimal NOT working example.

Comment: I think babel defines that. Do you load babel?

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking for German quotes, I assume you want to write in German, but you can change this. The important fact is that you need to use `babel`.

[image: quoted]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{name}
\familyname{name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2000--2010}{Some degree}
{
\glqq
University of Narnia
\grqq
}
{Some city, Some country}{}{}

\end{document}
```